# How to update rails plugins installed through git but in a svn repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, git, plugins

My rails app is in a svn repository, but several of the plugins are installed through git and later added to the svn repo.  How can I update these plugins?  I can't seem to get script/plugin update to do anything.  I'd really like to update activemerchant to get rid of the Inflector warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't made any local changes to the plugin and you don't need to track what changes to it the update will bring, you can just run `script/plugin install` again, passing in `--force` if you need to. For example:

```
script/plugin install --force git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec.git
```

Comment: that sort of works, but it puts the directory in an unknown state in terms of svn since it actually just deletes the vendor/plugin/active_merchant dir and reinstalls it.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a static copy of a plugin checked into Subversion, it can be a pain to update it via `script/plugin`, so here's what I end up doing in order to switch it from a static install to a Git checkout all within one Subversion commit:

```
git clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git ~/foobar
mv ~/foobar/.git rails_app/vendor/plugins/foobar/.git
rm -rf ~/foobar
cd rails_app/vendor/plugins
git reset --hard
```

Then make sure to add `.git` and everything else that has changed to the Subversion project and you will be all up-to-date. You can use other git commands to pull down updates, move to a different branch, etc. Then just check things in again once they are at the state that you want.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I do in this case, I remove the plugin directory then I commit to SVN, this will remove the old plugin in the repo. (I usually moved it in a tmp directory, just in case and delate it later once the new one is working fine)
I then reinstall the new version of the plugin, and commit again.
Easy.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to navigate to the plugin's directory and hit:

`git pull`
. I'm pretty sure that `script/install plugin` just checks the code out from the git repo.

Comment: well, what do you mean they were "installed through git". If they're not git repos then what do you mean by that?

Comment: they were installed from a git repo, but are housed in my app's svn repo.  if that makes sense.  see http://www.activemerchant.org/ and look at the plugiin/install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Git to be able to recognise the repository as a Git repository, you will need to add the `.git` subdirectory and everything under it to Subversion as well. Otherwise, the plugin will just look like another pile of source code and Git will say it's "Not a Git repository".

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same situation and used this solution: had paperclip installed as a plugin sitting in an svn repo as part of my app. Now I wanted to use the latest version instead and didnt change a bit of the paperclip plugin so I could easyly remove it from the app/svn and install it as a gem instead. done.